# Is there a way to upload files to Azure Storage account through URL?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have an API that allows users to upload and download files to my Azure Storage containers. With downloading files I have a simple function in my HTML script that uses user input information (SAS tokens, etc.) to create a URL where the user can download their file.

With file uploads, however, I have a whole separate Azure Function creating Blob Clients and Container Clients to upload data to Azure Storage containers. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to upload files to Azure Storage containers using a URL, with minimal code similar to how Azure Storage container file downloads work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking whether it is possible to create a container and / or upload a blob using http calls instead of the SDK. If that is the case you can leverage the REST Api.

For the examples below, I used a SAS token to authenticate,

To [create a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-container?tabs=azure-ad) you can use a PUT like this:

```
PUT https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&sv=2021-10-04&ss=btqf&srt=sco&st=2023-05-12T06%3A48%3A03Z&se=2023-05-13T06%3A48%3A03Z&sp=rwl&sig=I8EPwY4xhBWSbQKbPbasyXWnjwD%2BJTg8jHExZi9%2BU0w%3D
```

To [upload a blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob?tabs=azure-ad) to the container you can use a PUT as well

```
PUT https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob.txt?sv=2021-10-04&ss=btqf&srt=sco&st=2023-05-12T06%3A48%3A03Z&se=2023-05-13T06%3A48%3A03Z&sp=rwl&sig=I8EPwY4xhBWSbQKbPbasyXWnjwD%2BJTg8jHExZi9%2BU0w%3D
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob  

HELLO WORLD
```

(Note: I used an .http file in visual studio to create the examples, see [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-5-released/#api). So the code above can be put in a file with .http extension to test it)

Comment: This was exactly what I was asking for, thank you. Can you use POST as well?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there was a simpler way to upload files to Azure Storage containers using a URL

AFAIK, you need the container and blob clients to upload a file. Alternatively, you can use below commands in azure PowerShell Function with which you do not need clients.

You can integrate below commands into Azure PowerShell Function which do not uses clients:

```
$SASURL="https://rithwik.blob.core.windows.net/rithwik?sp==https&svV6V3dI0KJRxDY%2FtXh5jj8m%2BL8YpYU%3D"
$u = [System.Uri] $SASURL

$s = "rithwik"
$con = "rithwik"
$sas = $u.Query
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $s -SasToken $sas
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File "C:\Users\Downloads\76210027.html" -Container $con -Context $Context
```

[image]

File Uploaded as below:

[image]

And if you want to use [. Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299189/net-upload-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-sas-token/75309533#75309533), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75881575/error-to-upload-files-from-databricks-to-adls-with-python/75884096#75884096) SDKs or java you need to have the clients of block service or some azure storage packages.